# Get popover width in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have popover which display on hover. The width of the popover will be according to its content.

```
$("[rel='popover']").on('show.bs.popover', function () {
   //How to get popover width
});
```

I want to get the popover width when hovering.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut That will return width of the element which has popover. I need to get width of the popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

**aria-describedby attribute**

You can get the popover's element (and thus the width) by looking at the 'aria-describedby' attribute of the button. Note you can only get this attribute once the popover has been shown.

So,

```
$("[rel='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  var popoverID = $(this).attr('aria-describedby')
  console.log($("#"+popoverID).width());
});
```

**.next()**

You can also get the object using jQuery .next(), again after the popover is shown.

So,

```
$("[rel='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  console.log($($(this).next()).width());
});
```