# change popover style in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Popover is triggered on hover, I want to change style of the popover in jQuery.

I am able get the instance of the popover object when its hovered,

```
$("[rel='popover']").on('show.bs.popover', function () {

    if('some condition here'){

      $(this).popover({

       });
    }

});
```

And my CSS,

```
.popover{
  max-width: 500px;
 }
```

How can i override the max-width property defined in css for an instance of the popover?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. On showing of popover you are able to get the instance of it? Then just do `$(myinstance).css('max-width', myvalue);`

Comment: You want to change max-width only for one popover or for every popover on page?

Comment: @Yuri just for one popover

Comment: Have you tried `.on('show.bs.popover')` to use $(this).css('max-width', '500px'); as `this` should already be .popover element

Comment: @Yuri Yes I tried. this returns the element of popover not the popover object.

Answer (score 0):

See this post for how to get the popover element: [Get popover width in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905484/get-popover-width-in-jquery/33908180#33908180)

```
$("[rel='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  console.log($($(this).next()).width());
});
```

Then you can use:

```
$(myinstance).css('max-width', myvalue);
```

to change the width.

Demo at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ktLfzp7/